# Leaflet click to edit layer

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

i have polyline featuregroup on map and i want to edit layers on click.

```
if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
            const style = {
                color: InvestmentConstants.colors[$ctrl.investment.sector]
            };
            layer.setStyle(style);
            layer.enableEdit();
            layer.on('click',(layer) =>{
                someCb()
            })
        }
```

I have this but enableEdit function not work throws enableEdit is not a function error.

And map initialize snippet :

```
 $ctrl.map = new Map(
                "investment-edit-map",
                projectCenter,
                15,
                { 
                  mapSource: Map.Google,
                  editable:true 
                }
            );
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Edit : Changed enableEdit() functions line and now i got new error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editTools')`

Comment: According to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable

At "Install" -> You need Leaflet >= 1.0.0, and then include src/Leaflet.Editable.js.

At "Quick Start" you also have this info

Allow Leaflet.Editable in the map options:

    var map = L.map('map', {editable: true});

Have you done both ?

Comment: I done necessary configurations but still got same error.

Comment: editTools is a property of your map -> http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.Editable/doc/api.html

This error makes me feel like your map object is undefined

Your new Map() looks weird, the second parameter is supposed to be an {} of options, and you have "projectCenter" and 15 as third and then the {} of options

What is this Map class ? Not the leaflet one I think

Comment: Yes other options custom added but i think  not related this error. Looks weird my map instance has editTools everything in it but when enabling edit it throws error.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - without a complete and minimal example t'll be hard to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-event) .on('click') returns a MouseEvent so this code looks wrong

```
 layer.on('click',(layer) => {
     // layer here is a MouseEvent, not a layer
     layer.enableEdit(); // MouseEvent.enableEdit() is not a function
 })
```

Change it to

```
 layer.on('click',() => {
     layer.enableEdit();
 })
```

EDIT: The question was edited after my answer which makes my answer deprecated

Comment: Not deprecated thanks for answer.